# illegal option -- 1 in command for xargs shell command

Tags: shell

I have some files which I need to rename. I tried using xargs and mv commands, but i get the error

```
mv: illegal option -- 1
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

my dir contains files like -1,-2,-3

the command I use is

```
ls | xargs -I{} mv '{}' old'{}'
```

Comment: Obvously your file names look like options; why not add option `--` before them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the file names start with `-`. Most bash builtin commands treat anything preceded by `-` as an optional argument to the command. You can use `--` to indicate the end of options for the command. For example here, `-1` is taken as an argument to the `mv` command.

You can fix this by using

```
ls | xargs -I{} mv -- '{}' old'{}'
```

Note: You can use `-t` flag in `xargs` to see the command getting executed. Would probably make debugging easier.

From `man bash`

> Unless otherwise noted, each builtin command documented in this section as accepting options preceded by `-` accepts `--` **to signify the end of the options**.
>
> The `:`, `true`, `false`, and `test` builtins do not accept options and do not treat `--` specially.  The `exit`, `logout`, `break`, `continue`, `let`, and `shift` builtins accept and process arguments beginning with `-` without requiring `--`. Other builtins that accept arguments but are not specified as accepting options interpret arguments beginning with `-` as invalid options and require `--` to prevent this interpretation.
>
> Note that `echo` does not interpret `--` to mean the end of options.